# Is there a way to change the context path of storm ui

Tags: user-interface, apache-storm

The storm UI is accessed as below

```
http://<storm-host>:<storm-port>/
```

Is there a way to change the application context from / to /storm-ui 
ie to

```
http://<storm-host>:<storm-port/storm-ui
```

Tried changing in the storm.yaml to specify the contextpath, this is not honored.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the source code of Storm. It uses embedded jetty server and using ContextHandler the context path is set in the java code. So the source code  needs to be changed to set the context path